# Expo Local Notifications Not Scheduling

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

I have been working on scheduling local notifications (not push notifications) using expo. I am on SDK 44 and am using expo-notifications library. I have been digging through the expo documentation and trying their examples, but the notifications will not appear. The function runs, but I do not see any output on my device (using iPhone 8, not simulator).

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button onPress={schedulePushNotification} title="click here"/>
    </View>
  );
}
async function schedulePushNotification() {
  await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
      title: "You've got mail! ",
      body: 'Here is the notification body',
      data: { data: 'goes here' },
    },
    trigger: { seconds: 2 },
  });
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./app/assets/icon.png",
          "color": "#eb5e01"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ios require to grant notification push permission before triggering any notification.

```js
export async function allowsNotificationsAsync() {
  const settings = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
  return (
    settings.granted || settings.ios?.status === Notifications.IosAuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL
  );
}
```

Later in code

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button onPress={schedulePushNotification} title="click here"/>
    </View>
  );
}
async function schedulePushNotification() {

const hasPushNotificationPermissionGranted = await allowsNotificationsAsync()

if(hasPushNotificationPermissionGranted){
 await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
      title: "You've got mail! ",
      body: 'Here is the notification body',
      data: { data: 'goes here' },
    },
    trigger: { seconds: 2 },
  });

}
 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks! For future readers: make sure to add a requestPermissionsAsync() function to request permission on ios: 
async function requestPermissionsAsync() {
  return await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
    ios: {
      allowAlert: true,
      allowBadge: true,
      allowSound: true,
      allowAnnouncements: true,
    },
  });
}

Comment: Hi, i am currently stored dates in my db and want to remind user with a notification on that date. How do i achieve this?